# Удаление необходимой последовательности

Tags: регулярные-выражения, java

В данный момент есть одна большая строка, где может появиться слово в формате "ga- te", мне необходимо избавиться от "- ", чтобы вышло в итоге "gate". Хотел сделать это через регулярные выражения, можете что-то посоветовать по этому поводу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил вопрос с помощью

```
text = text.replaceAll("([a-zA-Z])- *([a-zA-Z])", "$1$2");
```

Comment: Велосипед написал. В php есть replaceAll().

Answer (score 1):

Метод класса `String:`

```
replaceAll("- ", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Например, так:

```
s/-\s//g;
```

Comment: Как-то не подошло.